# Graphics card is recognized as one single audio device

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

Connected to my Debian 10 (stable) system i have Genius 2.1 speakers and a Radeon RX 570 graphics card, which has 3x DisplayPort and a HDMI output (and  a DVI, but it's not relevant).

The Genius speakers are working fine (so the analog output can be ignored in the screenshots/code snippets below).

I have 2 monitors of the same type (with built in speakers) connected to DPs and an HDTV connected to the HDMI port, so in total i have 3 audio-capable devices connected to the same graphics card.

The problem is Alsa/PulseAudio recognizes this card as one single output device and i cannot switch between the ports. Audio is always being sent to the first monitor (which is connected to the first DisplayPort).

*pavucontrol* screenshot:
[image]

`aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I would like to be able to switch between the ports (or at least set the HDMI port as the default instead of the first DP), but unfortunately i have no idea how to approach this issue.

I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Possibly the ATI HDA hardware can only output a single sound connection, and it may not be obvious to the way the default configuration is picked up by ALSA and Pulseaudio how to switch. You can investigate your codec hardware by looking at `/proc/asound/card0/codec` (this will require a bit of reading up on it), and you can also look at `amixer` and see if ALSA at least has a way to switch between ports, even if this is not picked up by PulseAudio.

Comment: @dirkt I'll try looking into these, thank you.